# How to Create an Array from an Attribute 'data-sort' using Jquery of all Divs displayed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

If you have these Divs displayed:

```
<div data-sort='1'></div>
<div data-sort='4'></div>
<div data-sort='7'></div>
```

How can you create an array from their attributes 'data-sort'?

For example:

```
sortArray[0] = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
var sorts = $.map(
    $('div[data-sort]'), 
    function() { return $(this).attr('data-sort'); }
);
```

By calling the static `$.map`, I avoid creating an unnecessary jQuery object.

Comment: how would i retrieve the array values?

Comment: @taylor: `sorts` is a normal array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
<script>

  var sortArray = new Array();
  var _length = datas.length;
  var i = 0;

  while (i < datas)
  {
    var _value = $("div[data-sort]:lt(" + i + ")").attr("data-sort");
    sortArray.push(data_value);
  }
</script>
```